# Setting the Main Class and main() method in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, methods, program-entry-point, netbeans-8

Frustrated with Netbeans!!

I have created a Project with four classes.
Now I want to run the main() method of the Main class.
How do i do it. There is no other main() method in the whole package.

Note: There are more than one methods in the Main Class(including main()).

[Here is my Project Structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxHZE.jpg)

So What do i do??

And this written in Projects Properties--->Run--->computer.project.netbeans.ComputerProjectNetbeans
[(Screenshot is Here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjdIH.png)

And Here is My code Sample of my Main class:

```
class Main
{
    void Main()
    {
         \\Code
    }
    void A()
    {
         \\Code
    }
    void B()
    {
         \\Code
    }
    void C()
    {
         \\Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to the file containing main method right click and run file.

Comment: Clic to ALT+F6 to run each Main

Comment: Side note: consider to **not** learn about a powerful tool like (any) IDE at the same point while learning a new programming language. There is a certain merit in **first** learning how to program in language xyz; by using a simple text editor; and manually calling compiler / binaries from the command line ... and then, when you mastered that; and you understand all the essential things; then turn to an IDE. You see, the IDE hides a lot of stuff from you ... which is pretty bad; because you should know about all those "hidden" things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `public static void main(String[] args){}` method in which you will create an instance of your Main class in order for NetBeans to recognize "where" to start and begin executing your code. You can place the `main` method in the same class, after all your methods.

**Added code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    //Additional code
}
```